# How do i optimize image streamed with React and Web Socket?

Tags: reactjs, image, optimization, websocket, webcam

I have an interface to allow users perform face capture from an external webcam device. The webcam image is processed(with AI detections) on the Java backend. From the frontend we stream the image of the capturing in real-time to the client. The image is in HD.

The problem is that the streamed images lag a great deal. How do I optimize the render to make sure the webcam and the image rendered are in sync.

I get the streamed image like so:

```
          <SockJsClient
            url={`${BASE_HATEOAS_URL}/ws/`}
            topics={["face"]}
            onConnect={() => {
              console.log("connected");
            }}
            onDisconnect={() => {
              console.log("disconnected");
              setWebSocketInit(false);
            }}
            onMessage={(msg) => {
              
                setFaceCaptureData(msg.image);
            }}
          />
```

The capturing image is rendered like so:

```
<FaceUI.CaptureArea>
    <ImageWrapper>
        {faceCaptureData ? (
           <img
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${faceCaptureData}`}
              alt="camera feedback"
            />
          ) : (
           <PlaceholderIcon width="70%" height="70%" style={{ margin: "60px auto" }} />
           )}
     </ImageWrapper>
</FaceUI.CaptureArea>
```